# What are the `node:fs`, `node:path` etc. modules?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, require

Recently, while using a linter, I discovered that the names of some built-in packages where prepended with `node:`. I searched a lot but I didn't get any useful info. What is this `node:module` syntax?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html, https://nodejs.org/api/path.html?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Core modules can also be identified using the node: prefix, in which case it bypasses the require cache. For instance, require('node:http') will always return the built in HTTP module, even if there is require.cache entry by that name.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: And what's the use of this?

Comment: @LuisAFK This originally made use of the protocol part of URI syntax: eg. `http:`, `bitcoin:`, `mailto:`, `magnet:`, `ftp:` etc. with `node:` signifying that the resource is part of node's built-in standard library. It was mainly used for `import` statements which understand URI syntax. For `require()` it is used in a similar way except that `require()` only understands the `node:` protocol which makes it a kind of namespacing scheme whereas `import` understands `file:`, `node:` and `data:` (yes, you can base64 encode your entire module as a string and import it via data URI)